# What is the silver on the end of copper wire?

Tags: electrical

I am connecting a power cable to my dishwasher and I noticed the end of the copper wire looks like it has been dipped in solder. It is silver and very stiff. Should I be putting the wire nut on over this or cutting it off?

Both the power cable and the wires on the dishwasher have this material on the end of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's solder - it allows you to easily solder to the cable (if you needed to)

It's a very soft metal coating, a screw will make perfectly good contact through it.

Comment: They also help to stiffen up the ends of stranded wire (for when you need to insert it into a push connection) and it make it less likely to get breakage of individual strands or to oxidize (for both solid and stranded)

Comment: @Joe - good point about the strands. Although the engineer in me wants to say that you can't beat a copper-copper contact

Comment: @mgb : You can; that's why they sell so many gold plated plugs for home audio/video stuff ... most oxides are a resistor, so in low voltage situations it can be significant.

Comment: @Joe, yep copper-copper is good, but copper-gold-coper certainly beats copper-oxide-copper!

Comment: We've always called it "tinning the wire" because the solder is usually mostly tin (Sn).

Comment: Yes - The process of first coating the wire with solder is tinning - strictly speaking it's making the joint that is soldering